# How to transform a JSON using JOLT format

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Input JSON :

```json
{
  "mtime": "2023-03-14T01:00:00Z",
  "sid": "46",
  "tsa": "9.0",
  "tha": "7.8",
  "hra": "85.0",
  "tsf": null,
  "tss": null,
  "ens": "0.0",
  "dvt": null,
  "vvt": "4.8",
  "plu": "0.1",
  "hct": "26.0"
}
```

Desired Output JSON :

```json
{
  "Date": "2023-03-14 01:00:00",
  "data": [
    {
      "code": "tsa",
      "value": "9.0"
    },
    {
      "code": "tha",
      "value": "7.8"
    },
    {
      "code": "hra",
      "value": "85.0"
    },
    {
      "code": "tsf",
      "value": null
    },
    {
      "code": "tss",
      "value": null
    },
    {
      "code": "ens",
      "value": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "code": "dvt",
      "value": null
    },
    {
      "code": "vvt",
      "value": "4.8"
    },
    {
      "code": "plu",
      "value": "0.1"
    },
    {
      "code": "hct",
      "value": "26.0"
    }
  ],
  "stationname": "Station"
}
```

Comment: What did you try after reading [Getting Started](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt#Getting_Started) ?  (or should I have give a link to: [Apache NiFi Expression Language Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#overview) ?)

Comment: Hi Bhadraka, can you please voteup as well. Since only voting up increases tag badge which's important for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following transformation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "mtime": "Date", // rename the attribute
      "*": "data.&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Date": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": { // loop through all the attributes within the "data" array
          "$": "data[#2].code",
          "@": "data[#2].value"
        }
      },
      "#Station": "stationname" // add an attribute with fixed value
    }
  },
  { // just to sort the elements in the deisred order
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Date|data": "&",
      "stationname": "&"
    }
  },
  { // 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "DPortion1": "=substring(@(1,Date),0,10)",
      "DPortion2": "=substring(@(1,Date),11,19)",
      "Date": "=concat(@(1,DPortion1),' ',@(1,DPortion2))" // overwrite the Date's value by portions 
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the DPortion parameters
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "DPortion*": ""
    }
  }
]
```